# deriving re-useable terraform configuration from kops

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

I manage an established AWS ECS application with terraform. The terraform also manages all other aspects of each of 4 AWS environments, including VPCs, subnets, bastion hosts, RDS databases, security groups and so on.

We manage our 4 environments by putting all the common configuration in modules which are parameterised with variables derived from the environment specific terraform files.

Now, we are trying to migrate to using Kubernetes instead of Amazon ECS for container orchestration and I am trying to do this incrementally rather than with a big bang approach. In particular, I'd like to use terraform to provision the Kubernetes cluster and link it to the other AWS resources.

What I'd initially hoped to do was capture the terraform output from `kops create cluster`, generalise it by parameterising it with environment specific variables and then use this one kubernetes module across all 4 environments.

However, I now realise this isn't going to work because the k8s nodes and masters all reference the kops state bucket (in s3) and it seems like I am going to have clone that bucket and rewrite the files contained therein. This seems like a rather fragile way to manage the kubernetes environment - if I recreate the terraform environment, the related state kops state bucket is going to be inconsistent with the AWS environment.

It seems to me that kops generated terraform may be useful for managing a single instance of an environment, but it isn't easily applied to multiple environments - you effectively need one kops generated terraform per environment and there is noway to reuse the terraform to establish a new environment - for this you must fall back from a declarative approach and resort to an imperative `kops create cluster` command.

Am I missing a good way to manage the definition of multiple similar kubernetes environments with a single terraform module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you reached either conclusions, Terraform (which will cause more trouble than it will ever solve, that's definitely a tool to get rid of asap), or having to duplicate S3 buckets.
I'm pretty sure you'd be interested in kops's [cluster template](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/cluster_template.md) feature.
You won't need to generate, hack, and launch (and debug...) Terraform, and kops templates are just as easy if not significantly easier (and more specific...) to maintain than Terraform.
When kops releases new versions, you won't have to re-generate and re-hack your Terraform scripts either!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your perspective. I can see if you are approaching things from a "do everything in k8s stance" then a kops-lead approach has many benefits. I am coming from a perspective where I am very happy with Terraform for maintaining everything else in my environment (e.g. all the non-kubernetes stuff) and would like to use it for managing kubernetes if at all possible.

I think the middle ground is that I use Terraform to generate the values (such as subnets, vpc ids) for a kops cluster template but actually let kops do management of the k8s cluster itself (per: nwkf7g at goo.gl)

Comment: @jonseymour you're only happy with Terraform: A) for now B) because you're not familiar with more modern ways of achieving the same results. Terraform becomes especially pointless if you're running on more than one cloud, because they provide zero **abstraction**, it really is just a different syntax to things like CloudFormation. Try avoiding the approach you suggested, too. Just let kops set up its own VPCs, for security reasons... I wouldn't recommend re-using anything from your existing environment, unless you really know what you're doing.